# How i can access to [[Entries]] in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i seen a post in StackOverflow for the same problem but it's not exactly same for
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xVYH.png)

I've tried `message.guild.members.cache[0].key`or other lines like this but it returns "undefined" all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation of Collections](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) or [the guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html).

Collections are used like maps:

```
message.guild.members.cache.get('608972567386128395')
```

If you really want an array with all the values, you can use

```
message.guild.members.cache.values()
```

Comment: My code is a little bit hard, i want get a random member in every time i do the command, i know how to get a random value from a list but not with this "entries". (i tested .values and i got the same "[[Entries]]" and i don't know how i can get 1 of these 50 members

Comment: @Zarcross There literally is a [`random()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=random) method listed in the documentation.

Comment: Okay it works now, i didn't saw the random method